# Detect if external LED is on from ESP8266

Tags: led, esp8266, diy, detection

Intermediate DIY-er needs advice.

I'm trying to detect if my Air Conditioner power indicator LED is on from ESP8266 microcontroller (Wemos D1 Mini).

The indicator LED is on a small PCB module with a header, through which it is connected to the unit's controller. So injecting a couple of wires will not be a problem.

Here's a simplified schematics of the module connected to the controller:

[image]

The LED is switched on by the controller by pulling it to the ground. I have measured voltage between `GND` and `LED1` when LED is on and it was approximately 2V.

I want to connect the ESP8266 like on the schematics below to detect if LED is on (using pin `D5` with `INPUT_PULLUP`):

[image]

`D5` would output 3.3V.

The questions that I have:

1. Will this approach work to detect if LED is on?
2. Am I risking damaging the controller by feeding it 3.3V via `LED1` connection?

UPDATE: Another approach that I considered was using an optocoupler connected in series between the LED and the board:

[image]

Comment: The opto-coupler option is the way to go as it provides electrical isolation between the two circuits. You won't need additional series resistance. If anything you would reduce R8  somewhat but with a 13 V output it will make little difference.

Answer (score 4):

That won't work, and could damage the board.

Suggest adding a [2N7000](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/nds7002a-d.pdf) MOSFET as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkclsL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The output will be "high" when the LED is "on".

The resistors are optional but I would suggest using them. They may cause the LED to slightly glow 'on'. You can parallel the LED with 10K if that is objectionable.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Would using an optocoupler be ok too? E.g as on the schematics added to the bottom the original post. This way the LED should not glow 'on' when off.